# Sending date( in d/m/Y format) in url in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, controller, get

I am currently working on a project built in codeigniter . I am trying to send date in `d/m/Y` in url , eg `www.mydomain.com/guwahati-project-starting-12/12/2013`. But if I want to extract the controller name

```
$news_title = $this->uri->segment(1);
```

the above `$news_title` will only extract upto `guwahati-project-starting-12`. Is there any way I can extract the full string except replacing `/` with `-` ?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1179/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your controller name must include a date (I am assuming your full controller name is `guwahati-project-starting-12/12/2013`), then my recommendation would be to switch to using `dd-mm-yyyy` , as your date format will cause problems with codeigniters uri helper.

If you have to use `dd/mm/yyyy` then you could use `$this->uri->uri_string()` to get the full uri and then deal with the segmentation yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP's urlencode or rawurlencode function might work. Also, in your config.php file that's located in the application/config folder, you might need to edit it as follows.

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_,()&\/-';
```

Make sure to add the "/" and  in there.

Answer (score 0):

why not using urlencode ?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

and then when you want to load the date just urldecode
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urldecode.php

Answer (score 0):

url_title() function is available in the URL Helper... just load it and run it through this function.

This function will filter the string for characters and allows characters in the defined characters list in your config file (which you should most likely not edit)

--- sorry my answer isn't complete ---

few option, 1 is, why not use multiple segments... the "/" between your date make it different segments.
www.mydomain.com/guwahati-project-starting-12/12/2013

being guwahati-project-starting-12 = segment 1,
12 segment 2, and 2013 segment 3.

this will fail though, because segment 1 is class and 2 is controller...

try making
www.mydomain.com/class/function/guwahati-project/12/12/2013

now you have segment 3 your title, 4 your day, 5 your month and 6 your year

Answer (score 0):

another option, which i think is an overkill but is secured and url friendly
 is encrypting and decrypting it using. [HASHIDS](http://www.hashids.org/php/). like youtube and bitly does.

a link like this
`www.mydomain.com/guwahati-project-starting-12/12/2013`

can be made to
`www.mydomain.com/guwahati-project-starting/hjDm`

you can handle the parameter easily. Just dont forget to cast the date as `int`